# Upload to my_documents or my_photos folder OneDrive

Tags: rest, put, onedrive, live-sdk

I can upload to the top level directory in OneDrive with a PUT request at the URI:

I can upload a specific folder if I know it's specific ID:

"https://apis.live.net/v5.0/folder.5f5fb682f4910ce0.5F5FB682F4910CE0!189/files/someFile.txt?access_token=xyz123"

But how do I upload to a folder using it's friendly name, e.g. my_photos. The OneDrive documentation isn't helpful - it seems to gloss over this. It mentions friendly names, but I don't know how to use them as part of a URI PUT request.

edit: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj680723 shows using GETs with friendly names, but what about PUTs? I can't figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to upload to a 'special folder' by aiming your PUT at the same base URL you use for GETs, except with "/files" added on, like you do for normal folders. So: `PUT https://apis.live.net/v5.0/skydrive/my_photos/files/foo.jpg`

That said, we recommend you consider using the [new OneDrive API](http://dev.onedrive.com) instead. It is more powerful and better documented than the one you're using now. Here are the sections on [special folders](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/special_folders.htm) and [uploading files](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload.htm). In the new API, the upload I mentioned above would look like `PUT https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/special/photos:/foo.jpg`

Comment: Can you provide a sample code for uploading files to one drive using this api