# Using One Drive with Visual Studio Lightswitch HTML 2013

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-lightswitch, onedrive, lightswitch-2013

I am currently trying to learn how to access a one drive folder via javascript however there is one main concept which is confusing me:

I create a folder called **test** which has the name of something like this:

```
folder.a6b2a7e8f2515e5e.A6B2A7E8F2515E5E!164
```

now using this code provided by Microsoft, is there a way to just use the word "Test" rather than this long code? my reason being this is not user friendly and cannot easily be set up... otherwise I shall have to store each name in a database rather than referring to say a project name?

```
function readFolderProperties_onClick() {
    WL.login({
        scope: "wl.skydrive"
    }).then(
        function (response) {
            WL.api({
                path: "folder.a6b2a7e8f2515e5e.A6B2A7E8F2515E5E!164",
                method: "GET"
            }).then(
                function (response) {
                    document.getElementById("infoArea").innerText = 
                        "Folder properties: name = " + response.name + ", ID = " + response.id;                
                }, 
                function (responseFailed) {
                    document.getElementById("infoArea").innerText = 
                        "Error reading folder properties: " + responseFailed.error.message;
                }
            );
        }, 
        function (responseFailed) {
            document.getElementById("infoArea").innerText = 
                "Error signing in: " + responseFailed.error_description;
        }
    );
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh826531.aspx

thanks for any help on this

Answer (score 0):

As covered in the following MSDN article, friendly names can only be used in certain situations:

[Common tasks in accessing Microsoft OneDrive from your app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj680723.aspx) (under the 'Using friendly names to access certain OneDrive folders' section)

However, as mentioned in the following MSDN article and stackoverflow post, a newer OneDrive API is available which may help:

[The Live SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn631819.aspx#sectionSection0) (under the 'What's new' section)

[Upload to my_documents or my_photos folder OneDrive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31690135/1301937)

More specifically, the following details this new API's approach to addressing resources by a friendly path:

[Addressing resources in a drive on OneDrive](https://dev.onedrive.com/misc/addressing.htm) (under the 'Path-based addressing' section)

Comment: I have followed this and got no where with lightswitch, stand-a-lone applications however are much easier to get this working, thanks for the links though

Comment: Out of interest, what type of issues did you encounter when trying to implement this in a LightSwitch project?

Comment: well i haven't spent to much time with this, alls i was trying to achieve was the creation of a folder and i did not succeed. at a later date i shall look more into this and hopefully get it working. im sure it will be more than possible, and wouldn't be surprised if Microsoft linked them together in some way either